# Errors with clipboard.js in React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, clipboard.js

I’m trying to use clipboard.js in a React component, and it causes my devserver to start failing with the Node error:
`ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/home/me/code/board/webapp/node_modules/matches-selector/index.js:6:13)`

I initialize the clipboard in `componentDidMount` but am still getting this error. I actually think the error may have something to do with my import, because even when I don’t actually initialize the clipboard (but include the import) I get the error. Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Relevant code (styling excluded):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Clipboard from 'clipboard';

export default class CodeSnippet extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        new Clipboard('.copyButton', {
            target: () => document.getElementById('snippet')
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (      
            <div style={styles.snippetCopy}>
                <div id="snippet" style={styles.snippet}>
                    {'this text will copy'}
                </div>
                <button
                    className={"copyButton"}
                    id="clipper"
                    data-clipboard-text='snippet'
                    style={styles.buttonStyle}
                    text={'Copy code'}>
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't require clipboard.js if you're doing server side rendering. It's annoying but instead of installing via npm, they suggest including the script manually like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.12/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```

https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/issues/157

Comment: I should add that the reason you can't load the lib on the server side is because it immediately tries to access `window.Element` which obviously doesn't exist until the page is rendered in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

I created a fiddle updating your code. It's a suggestion of integrating `clipboardjs` and `React`, using [ref's](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) and  [clipboardjs' text function](https://clipboardjs.com/).

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/L54ky6hj/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! That is a much better integration of React. I'm still getting the Node error upon importing clipboard though.

Comment: I teste here in a react test project, and it worked. Try updating your packages (react, clipboard) (`npm update clipboard`) and/or reinstalling it (`npm uninstall clipboard && npm install clipboard --save`). Try the same with react. Are you using webpack?

Comment: The "copied" message (tooltip) is missing. I'm wondering if this is a clipboard js bug if used in react